# Error when it comes to inflate the MapView in Layout-File

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, mapbox

I got an error when it comes to inflate the MapView in the XML-File.
 The access token should be correct and i also include the telematics in the manifest. I use these version of mapbox `'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:4.1.0-beta.3@aar'`

Here is my Layout-File.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:mapbox="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapviewmapbox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    mapbox:access_token="@string/accessToken"
    mapbox:center_latitude="40.73581"
    mapbox:center_longitude="-73.99155"
    mapbox:style_url="mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9"
    mapbox:zoom="11" />

</RelativeLayout>`
```

And the Java-File:

```
package de.example.navdrawemap_2.maptest.Maps;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapboxMap;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;

import de.example.navdrawemap_2.maptest.R;

public class MapMapboxActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private MapView mapView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map_mapbox);

    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapviewmapbox);
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(MapboxMap mapboxMap) {


        }});
}

      /*
    TextView textViewTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.texttitel);
    TextView textViewTitleBig = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.texttitel_big);
    TextView textViewSnippet = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textsnippet);
    Intent intentbundleStrings = getIntent();

    if (intentbundleStrings != null) {
                    textViewTitleBig.setText(intentbundleStrings.getStringExtra("title"));
        // textViewTitle.setText(intentbundleStrings.getStringExtra("title"));
        // Titel im Header nachtragen
        textViewSnippet.setText(intentbundleStrings.getStringExtra("snippet"));
    }else{
        textViewTitle.setText(intentbundleStrings.getStringExtra("N.A."));
        textViewSnippet.setText(intentbundleStrings.getStringExtra("N.A."));
    } */




// Add the mapView lifecycle to the activity's lifecycle methods
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mapView.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mapView.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory();
    mapView.onLowMemory();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mapView.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

}`

The Logcat shows the following:

```
06-21 15:46:06.753 13892-13892/de.example.navdrawemap_2.maptest E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              Process: de.example.navdrawemap_2.maptest, PID: 13892
                                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.example.navdrawemap_2.maptest/de.example.navdrawemap_2.maptest.Maps.MapMapboxActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2198)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
                                                                                  at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
                                                                                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                               Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@twain, thankfully you posted your code in Github.  The source of the problem was the permissions.

Here is the [Github commit that fixes this up](https://github.com/roblabs/BerlinClimb_Beta/commit/6498afe87eab566f5af06bcdc2bb8137276b9e65).

The clue that I saw was in the log, the key line of the source for android permissions is here.

> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/mapbox/mapboxsdk/location/LocationServices;

It is very cryptic, but I have run into this problem before, therefore it lead me to the solution.

You needed

```
android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE
```

instead of

```
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
```

I also reset the Mapbox Android SDK to latest release, but I'm not sure what that affect had.

```
compile ('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:4.0.1@aar'){
    transitive=true
}
```

Here is the example of the Mapbox map from your app over Potsdam.

[image: Mapbox Map]

Comment: I add the package name and also changed the tools:context  to ".Maps.MapMapboxActivity" . But the second one doesn't solve the problem. What do you mean with "And the name of you class —" ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @twain, I totally changed my answer.  Please accept if this is correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Really cool... I am realtiv new to SO and github, but now I know the great advantages.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be memory issue. I had similar problems on inflating complex views. Try to reduce map width and height.

Comment: Not really. I reduce the map-object but it does not work and shows the same Error. :(

Answer (score -1):

You need to add

```
Mapbox.getInstance(getApplicationContext(), "MY_DEFAULT_PUBLIC_API_KEY");
```

In the **application class** instead in activity.